# Calling a function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery function is something like:

```
$.a.b.c();
```

Now I am trying to call it dynamically:

```
var temp = b;
$.a.temp.c();
```

But obviously its not working. How do I get this to work. Please feel free to edit the question title, as am not sure how to really phrase the question.

Comment: presumably there is a function called "c" that is a property of temp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the brackets instead of the dot notation:

```
var temp = 'b';
$.a[temp].c();
```